# Install GNU Emacs GUI in Fedora

Tags: emacs, fedora, gui, yum, fedora-14

I've installed the "emacs" package from `yum`, but typing `emacs` at the terminal doesn't launch the GUI version. I was under the impression it installed by default, and `emacs -nw` would be used for the terminal version.

Is there a GUI package available for Fedora 14 (GNOME)? I couldn't find "emacs-gtk" or "emacs-gnome" or any X packages with `yum search emacs-`.

Edit: To clarify, this is about **GNU Emacs** and not XEmacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. I thought I'd done `yum install emacs`, but apparently, I had not. The version included with the base Fedora system doesn't have X support, but you can get it via the package.

```
# yum install emacs
```

Answer (score 0):

Try quering your package database for **xemacs**

Comment: 'GNU emacs' and 'xemacs' are two different programs (forked many years ago). I do not know the solution (not being a Fedora user) but I know this is not it.

Comment: No, this isn't it. Does anyone actually run Emacs with a GUI in Fedora/RHEL/CentOS?